# Bootstrap Modal mouse wheel issues in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, html, bootstrap-modal

Scrolling inside a modal window causes the page in the background to also scroll. Scrolling with up/down arrow keys work fine in Modal but not with mouse/touchpad scrolling. This issue is not present in firefox.

**Tried**:

```
.modal.fade.in {
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Tried but not worked on my Chrome version 49.0.2623.108

**PS**: Referenced site https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16297

Please help me , I couldn't understand how to solve this.

Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/9nuhnbbv/119/

**Updated**: Hey Guys, Plz Reply

Comment: I always find that questions about browser issues vs. code issues is pretty easy to pinpoint as to which one is causing the error: Without more code (specifically your HTML and JS), all I can really tell you is to go to the Bootstrap website and see if the demo works for you. If it doesn't, then it's an issue with your browser. If it does, then it is an issue with your code. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals If it is your code, then provide some HTML and JS to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but all demos are working fine for me . If there a problem in my code then how would be that code worked in firefox browser.

Comment: Until I can see the code the only answer I can give is: I don't know. Try to give shortened demo in a JSFiddle: http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: I have created a snippet in js fiddle but here it is working . On scrolling modal it  has been correctly scroll but not in my code in chrome. Please suggest.                                                                                                               http://jsfiddle.net/9nuhnbbv/117/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your fiddle, I can't recreate the issue. However, if you want to force it to disable the scroll of the background element you can try to do it in JQuery:

**JQuery**

```
$('#addEjuiceModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('body').addClass('scroll-disable'); // or whatever div is scrolling
});

$('#addEjuiceModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
   $('body').removeClass('scroll-disable'); // or whatever div is scrolling
});
```

**CSS**

```
.scroll-disable{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9nuhnbbv/121/

Comment: Take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  on following MCVE guidelines in Stack Overflow. I would need a reproducible piece of code to really know how to fix it. If it is just a browser incompatibility, it may be a bug in the browser. Try rolling back to another version and see if it works. The JSFiddle you present **must** be able to reproduce the error.